# Gitlab-ci : how to use git command with maven image

Tags: git, maven, gitlab-ci

In my script I want to:

1- increase the pom version (working)

2- build the project (working)

3- commit and push the pom.xml to gitlab (not working)

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-10-slim

variables:
  APP_NAME: demo

stages:
- build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  - mvn package -P build
  - git --version
```

I get this error because (I think) the maven image I use doesn't include git:

```
$ git --version
/usr/bin/bash: line 68: git: command not found
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Make a custom image that contains both maven and git and use that for your build
2. Install git inside your build, for example in a before_script step:

   `- apt-get update && apt-get install -y git`

Answer (score 0):

You should [install git first](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) if you want to use it. You will not get this error, after you install it.